# Wifi frequently disconnected when using bluetooth audio on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, bluetooth

Since upgrading my DELL XPS 15 9570 from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 (I also upgraded to 20.04 shortly but just to upgrade to 22.04), the Wi-Fi connection has been really terrible: It disconnects after reconnecting for just a couple of minutes (sometimes even less) and this happens very frequently. I have been searching for solutions for a while, and have tried a lot of things such as

1. Upgrading the kernel (my current kernel is 6.3.2 stable), or
2. changing the Wi-Fi power saving mode, but none of them really worked.

Recently, I figured out that ONLY when my laptop does not connect to anything via BLUETOOTH, the Wi-Fi is stable. When Bluetooth connection is used, Wi-Fi frequently disconnects again. I'm not sure why this is the case, as this didn't happen back then with Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm posting to look for a permanent solution where I can connect Wi-Fi and Bluetooth simultaneously.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

> 3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
> Subsystem: Rivet Networks Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
> Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
> Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
> 3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)

Comment: Maybe this might help:  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478211